# Indentation of modules

Tags: agda

When reading the documentation, I had the impression that definitions inside modules should be indented. However, when browsing the standard library or people's files, it does not seem that people indent their modules, at least not the "main" module corresponding to the file.

Specifically, when I am writing a file "Foo.agda", should I do

```
module Foo where
  a : ...
  a = ...
```

or

```
module Foo where
a : ...
a = ...
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Agda determines what belongs to a module by indentation. However, the (unique) top-level module is an exception - what belongs there is unambiguous, it's the whole file!

This means you can use both styles. I personally go with no indentation, it's slightly more readable and consistent with the stdlib style.